# Нажатие на кнопку с помощью тачпада

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка на форме, есть два селектора: `button` и `button:active`. При нажатии мышью на кнопке — стиль из селектора `button:active` применяется, но если нажать на кнопку с помощью тачпада — нет. Как сделать чтобы стиль применялся в обоих случаях?

Comment: А лично вижу что при нажатии (и зажатии) и через мышку, и через тачпад у меня псевдоселектор `:active` срабатывает (на время нажатия). Но я говорю про Chrome. Другие браузеры не смотрел. Может вы имеете ввиду какой-то специфичный браузер или что-то другое?

Comment: Тоже смотрю в хроме, но не нажимать на кнопку, а именно на сам тачпад

Comment: Это как "не нажимать на кнопку, а на тачпад"? У вас есть курсор и с помощью тачпада вы действуете также как и мышкой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `ontouchstart`:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

или

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);
```

Это хак для Mobile Safari.

Если не помогает, попробуйте подключить библиотеку [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужен какой нибудь псевдокласс, но в css такого нет.
Так что без js не обойтись.

```
$('button').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('select');
}).bind('touchend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('select');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте завязаться на `button:focus`